# Gorilla middleware authentication for specific routes not working

Tags: http, go, gorilla

Im writing a http router for a API and some routes require authentication while some dont.

I dont want to ask for authentication on every route, so I split them up.

But theres a problem:

**POST /account** <-- This is a account registration endpoint, and does not require authentication

**DELETE /account** <-- This does require authentication to delete the current account

I have no idea how to seperate these properly, also my current attempt at making the middleware different for the two is failing:

```golang
package httpServer

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "httpServer/handlers"
    "httpServer/middlewares"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/justinas/alice"
)

func Init() {
    log.Println("Initializing http routes...")

    defaultmiddlewares := alice.New(middlewares.Logger, middlewares.Recover)
    authmiddlewares := alice.New(middlewares.Authenticator)

    var mainRouter = mux.NewRouter()
    var authRouter = mux.NewRouter()

    // No auth required to call this
    mainRouter.HandleFunc("/health", handlers.HealthGet).Methods("GET")        // Get API health

    // authrouter should be a extension of main router (i think)
    mainRouter.Handle("/", authmiddlewares.Then(authRouter))

    // Authentication is not required for this
    mainRouter.HandleFunc("/account", handlers.AccountPost).Methods("POST")                    // Create an account

    // Authentication is required for this
    authRouter.HandleFunc("/account", handlers.AccountDelete).Methods("DELETE")                // Delete my account

    // WebSocket endpoint:
    authRouter.HandleFunc("/ws", handlers.UpgradeWs)
    authRouter.HandleFunc("/ws/", handlers.UpgradeWs) // If i dont add this it doesnt work??
    
    // Register mainRouter
    http.Handle("/", defaultmiddlewares.Then(mainRouter))
}
```

Calls to **GET /health** are just fine:[image: screenshot from postman]
But calls to **DELETE /account** are failing with a **404 Not Found**:[image: screenshot from postman]

(Also near the end of the **Init()** function i register a websocket endpoint, for some reason if i dont register both those endpoints it fails to connect?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialised two routers `mainRouter` and `authRouter`  and only start `mainRouter`. `DELETE /account` is bound to `authRouter` . That is not started and listening. That is why 404 coming.

And you can write custom middleware implementations to [gorilla/mux Middleware interface](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/master/middleware.go#L14) and use with `gorilla/mux` router. Example code is like below

```
func Init() {
    log.Println("Initializing http routes...")
    
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    middleware := Middleware{
        // inject any dependency if you need
    }
    r.Use(middleware.MiddlewareFunc)

    // No auth required to call this
    r.HandleFunc("/health", handlers.HealthGet).Methods("GET")        // Get API health

    // authrouter should be a extension of main router (i think)
    r.Handle("/", authmiddlewares.Then(authRouter))

    // Authentication is not required for this
    r.HandleFunc("/account", handlers.AccountPost).Methods("POST")                    // Create an account

    // Authentication is required for this
    r.HandleFunc("/account", handlers.AccountDelete).Methods("DELETE")                // Delete my account


    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

// Middleware your custom middleware implementation
type Middleware struct {}

func (m Middleware) MiddlewareFunc(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        
    // you can check request method and paths and you can do authentications here
    //eg := method = DELETE and path = /account, do authentication

        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
I ended up adding a subrouter and doing authentication on that, works great